# React router v6 how to use `navigate`. Axios interceptors

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

**React router v6 how to use `navigate`. Axios interceptors**

There are many examples on the Internet. But how to do it right? If possible, please provide a detailed description. Thanks!

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://URL.ru/",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
})

HTTP.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        //navigate('/login')
    }
    return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

Comment: This seems fine to me, dont see the problem?

Comment: @DamianBusz, The problem is that you can't use hook useNavigate

Comment: @КристианЧайковский ah alright, you mean because its a hook and it cant be used inside interceptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass navigate down the interceptor if you will wrap it in a functional component and initialize it inside your app.js

First, lets create a function that will work as our interceptor Promise, its supposed to take navigate as its param

```
const AxiosInterceptorsSetup = navigate => {
    HTTP.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
        error => {
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                navigate('/login');
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
};

export default AxiosInterceptorsSetup;
```

Now we need to create functional component inside app.js that will use our **AxiosInterceptorsSetup**

```
function AxiosInterceptorNavigate() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    AxiosInterceptorsSetup(navigate);
    return <></>;
}


function App(props) {
   return (
       <BrowserRouter>
           {<AxiosInterceptorNavigate />}
            {...}
           </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
   );
}
```

Comment: This will register a new interceptor handler for every render

Comment: const navigate = useNavigate();
  const navigateRef = useRef(navigate);

  useEffect(() => {
  ... 
     navigateRef.current('/login');
  ...
  }, []);